# Will coiling a mains power electrical cord cause interference?

Tags: rf, interference

I am a maker working on a lamp design in which a decorative power cord is wound through the structure, creating a coil down the lamp's main structure. The coils are about 3cm apart and the same in diameter, and the power standard is 220V.

I'm pretty certain that this isn't in any way dangerous, however will coiling the cord in this way cause any interference with other electronic devices? Are there any other concerns?

Comment: Shouldn't matter if you use regular two or three wire cable. One thing to watch out for is only the case with high currents, you don't want your cable to heat up when it is all coiled up in one spot.

Comment: Where are the "other electronic devices"? Inside the coil?

Comment: Use high temperature cable if the lamp is tungsten filament.

Comment: @Samuel, there's no devices inside the cable, I mean nearby devices like a television, radio, or computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coils, if "air-cored", meaning that no metal passes though the center of the coils, should be relatively benign. Especially if both wires are routed together in the coil. However, if they are routed separately, and have any metal though the centers, then they will behave at least slightly as inductors and/or transformers, and three things may happen. 1. They metal or coils may get warm. 2. They may reduce the amount of power reaching the lamp. 3. They may audibly "hum" with the mains frequency. Any metal passing through them may also generate a current (transformer action) which may be negligible, or rather significant depending on the exact design. A picture here would be worth a thousand words.